CPI with unauthorized signer or writable account
I know this question is repeated again, but I look over all the StackExchange to solve the CPI problem, but none is working for me.
I created a smart contract in which the user will toss a coin and x amount of sol will be transferred to the smart contract's well account, probably, but when I call the distribute_rewards function, I'm getting an error of "Cross-program invocation with an unauthorised signer or writable account," and I don't know what's the problem and have been stuck on this problem for two days. I'm testing it out in the Solana playground, and if I make the well as signer, then I'm getting an error of Testing 'initialise'...❌ Test 'initialise' failed: 
Reason: Error processing Instruction 2.
Code:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use solana_program::sysvar::clock::Clock;
use anchor_lang::system_program::{self, Transfer};


declare_id!("7Z3D7VoA53M4TS1UbgwWyT8AuTRSb9LYziNhaNNXzdGB");

#[program]
pub mod wishing_well {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, initial_toss_price: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let well = &mut ctx.accounts.well;
        well.owner = *ctx.accounts.user.key;
        well.total_sol_collected = 0;
        well.toss_price = initial_toss_price;
        well.last_distribution_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;
        Ok(())
    } 

    pub fn toss_coin(ctx: Context<TossCoin>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {

        // Ensure the amount sent is sufficient
     let well_info = ctx.accounts.well.to_account_info(); // Create an immutable reference to the well account

     let well = &mut ctx.accounts.well; // Create a mutable reference

     require!(amount >= well.toss_price, WishingWellError::InsufficientFunds);

     // Transfer SOL from the user to the well account
     let cpi_accounts = anchor_lang::system_program::Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        to: well_info, // Use the immutable reference here
     };

     let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info();
     let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
     anchor_lang::system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

      // Now you can safely use the mutable reference to well
     well.total_sol_collected += amount;

     //@Dev Storing the time and user adrress in participant vector
      let participant = Participant {
            key: ctx.accounts.user.key(),
            timestamp: Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp,
        };
        well.participants.push(participant);

     //  well.participants.push(ctx.accounts.user.key());

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn distribute_rewards(ctx: Context<DistributeRewards>) -> Result<()> {
        let mut fees;
        let first_prize_u64:u64;
         let second_prize_u64:u64;
        let third_prize_u64:u64;
        


        {
        let well = &mut ctx.accounts.well;
        
        let current_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;
        require!(
            current_time >= well.last_distribution_time + (3 * 60),
            WishingWellError::DistributionTimeError
        );

        require!(well.participants.len() >= 3, WishingWellError::NotEnoughParticipants);

           // Calculate fees first
        fees = (well.total_sol_collected * 35) / 1000; // 3.5% fees
        well.total_sol_collected -= fees;


        // Use fixed-point arithmetic for more precise calculations
        let total_sol_scaled = well.total_sol_collected * 10000000;
        let first_prize = total_sol_scaled * 50 / 100;
        let second_prize = total_sol_scaled * 30 / 100;
        let third_prize = total_sol_scaled * 20 / 100;

        // Convert back to u64
         first_prize_u64 = first_prize / 10000000;
         second_prize_u64 = second_prize / 10000000;
         third_prize_u64 = third_prize / 10000000;

        // Ensure total rewards equal total collected minus fees
        let total_rewards = first_prize_u64 + second_prize_u64 + third_prize_u64;
        require!(
            total_rewards <= well.total_sol_collected,
            WishingWellError::RewardCalculationError
        );


        // Calculate remaining sol after fees and rewards
        let remaining_sol = well.total_sol_collected - total_rewards;
        let fees = (remaining_sol * 35) / 1000; // 3.5% fees

        // well.total_sol_collected = remaining_sol - fees;
        well.participants.clear();
        well.last_distribution_time = current_time;
        }
        let well_account_info = ctx.accounts.well.to_account_info();


        {
            // Transfer fees to the owner's account using CPI
            let cpi_accounts_fee = Transfer {
                from: well_account_info.clone(),
                to: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
            };
            let cpi_context_fee = CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts_fee);
            system_program::transfer(cpi_context_fee, fees)?;
        }
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info();

        // {
        //     // Transfer rewards to each winner using CPI

        //  // First winner transfer
        //     let cpi_accounts_first = Transfer {
        //     from: well_account_info.clone(),
        //     to: ctx.accounts.first_winner.to_account_info(),
        //     };
        //  let cpi_context_first = CpiContext::new(cpi_program.clone(), cpi_accounts_first);
        //      system_program::transfer(cpi_context_first, first_prize_u64)?;

        //     // Log first winner
        //  ctx.accounts.well.winners.push(Winner {
        //     key: ctx.accounts.first_winner.key(),
        //   amount: first_prize_u64,
        //  });

        // }
        // {
        //    // Second winner transfer
        //  let cpi_accounts_second = Transfer {
        //    from: well_account_info.clone(),
        // to: ctx.accounts.second_winner.to_account_info(),
        // };
        //  let cpi_context_second = CpiContext::new(cpi_program.clone(), cpi_accounts_second);
        //  system_program::transfer(cpi_context_second, second_prize_u64)?;

        //  // Log second winner
        //      ctx.accounts.well.winners.push(Winner {
        //       key: ctx.accounts.second_winner.key(),
        //         amount: second_prize_u64,
        //  });

        // }
        // {
        //     // Third winner transfer
        //  let cpi_accounts_third = Transfer {
        //  from: well_account_info.clone(),
        //   to: ctx.accounts.third_winner.to_account_info(),
        //  };
        //  let cpi_context_third = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts_third);
        //  system_program::transfer(cpi_context_third, third_prize_u64)?;

        //  // Log third winner
        //  ctx.accounts.well.winners.push(Winner {
        //      key: ctx.accounts.third_winner.key(),
        //     amount: third_prize_u64,
        //   });
        // }


        Ok(())
    }
    

    pub fn change_toss_price(ctx: Context<ChangeTossPrice>, new_price: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let well = &mut ctx.accounts.well;
        well.toss_price = new_price;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 32 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 32 * 100)]
    pub well: Account<'info, WishingWell>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TossCoin<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub well: Account<'info, WishingWell>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DistributeRewards<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub well: Account<'info, WishingWell>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub first_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub second_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub third_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>, // Add the owner field here
     /// CHECK: Safe because this is the system program
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeTossPrice<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
    pub well: Account<'info, WishingWell>,
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct WishingWell {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub total_sol_collected: u64,
    pub toss_price: u64,
    pub last_distribution_time: i64,
    // pub participants: Vec<Pubkey>, 
    pub participants: Vec<Participant>,
    pub winners: Vec<Winner>, // New vector for storing winners
}

#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Participant {
    pub key: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
}

#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Winner {
    pub key: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
}


#[error_code]
pub enum WishingWellError {
    #[msg("Insufficient funds sent.")]
    InsufficientFunds,
    #[msg("Distribution can only happen every 3 days.")]
    DistributionTimeError,
    #[msg("Not enough participants for a draw.")]
    NotEnoughParticipants,
    #[msg("Reward calculation error.")]
    RewardCalculationError,
} 



could you share the full error log?

@Jimii I was using Solana playground and i can only see the error of "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account" when i call the Distribute rewards function.

I guess the problem is that your well account is not a signer. If you want to take sol from that account it needs to be a signer of the transaction.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DistributeRewards<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub well: Signer<'info, WishingWell>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub first_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub second_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub third_winner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>, // Add the owner field here
     /// CHECK: Safe because this is the system program
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

Another approach you can take is make the Well account a PDA:
Here is a tutorial showing how you can use a PDA as an account that saves and pays out SOL:
https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/tiny-adventure-two

For well account, If I make it signer and chose owner and well then it gives error of signer verification failed and I make the owner and signer again in Solana Playground then again error as at a time only once can sign the transaction.

You can sign with both accounts. The signer field is an array. For further details i would need to see the client code. Maybe you can paste it in your question
